# Storing elements into a grid

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, shuffle

How to shuffle and store each character of the string inside the table such that 1st letter of the pair is in random row position and 2nd letter of the pair is in random column position so that the 2 characters do not conflict in same row or column?
this is my code for creating a 7x7 grid

```
<table border="5px" cellspacing="30" align="center" class="table-bordered"  style="color:#FFFFFF" width="400px" height="200px">
<% for(int row=1; row <= 7; row++) { %>
<tr>
<%      for(int col=1; col<=7; col++) { %>
<td></td>
    <% } %>
</tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

And this is my code for shuffling of a string

```
<script>
  function f1() {
    var str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()<>?";
    var shuffled = str.split('').sort(function({
      return0.2Math.random();
    }).join('');
    document.write(shuffled);
  }   
</script>
```

Now I want this shuffled string to get split up and get stored into each cell of the table.

Comment: The code for your function would be more readable if you added it to a code formatted block. Also it would be good if you could explain in more detail what the code is trying to achieve.
Can you explain what the string would look like as a result of someone answering your question?

Comment: i've created grid separately and my string has been shuffled separately.Say my string is "hello",after it gets shuffled it can be"elohl" or"lloel" anything like that.now i want this shuffled string  to get into the grid occupying each cell.i.e. each character in a single cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you troubling your `jsp` to do this? Let your scripting (`jQuery`) do this. In your HTML add `id` attribute to your table like this,

```
<div id="myDiv">
   <table id="myTable" border="5px" cellspacing="30" 
       align="center" class="table-bordered" width="400px" height="200px">
             <!-- Your content goes here -->
   </table>
</div>
```

And in your scripting use the shuffled string you can create table like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var myWord = "hello";  //Use any shuffled string
     var length = myWord.length; 
     var createTable = '<tr>';
     for ( var i=0; i < length; i++) {   //Iterate through each character
       if (myWord.charAt(i) != " ") {
           // Create as table cell
           createTable = createTable+'<td>'+myWord.charAt(i)+'</td>';
       } 
     };
     createTable = createTable+'</tr>';
     $("#myTable").append(createTable);
});
```

Check the [**working sample**](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/05sqq48d/6/).

**Update :**

Hope this is you're asking, how to find specific table definition.

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
     $(this).find("td:eq(0)").html("Your Shuffled Character maybe h"); // First cell    
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! Its working but i want to my characters to get filled in 7x7 grid at random positions. if "hello" is my string it will  occupy 5 cells and the rest of the cells has to be filled with numbers or any other special character

Comment: After creating table cells you can [Randomize table cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190628/randomize-table-cells#5193114).

Comment: for your purpose, shuffle your word with that function itself. Let the function gives you the shuffled word like `lohe89l`. Then you can use my answer for creating the table cells accordingly.

Comment: Yeah!!! It worked with my shuffled string but then as i said before i have no idea of how to find the position of the cell in the table to place my character.I mean the cell position.

Comment: Check my update section of answer, give id to your table and (say`mytable` in my example) add your shuffled character to that. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Sorry since am new to jquery i dont know where to use your update answer in the code.Can you just help me with this

Comment: Let the table create without the character, once it's created add the updated code.